# Gradle error :app:processDevDebugManifest FAILED when added <supports-screens>

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am replacing the < compatible-screens > to < supports-screens >. and it was dependency issue with ZXing library code to scan bar code. Error is displayed below.

> AndroidManifest.xml:121:9-37 Error:   Attribute
>   supports-screens@smallScreens value=(false) from
>   AndroidManifest.xml:121:9-37  is also present at [xyz:unspecified]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:17:9-36 value=(true).
>
> :app:processDevDebugManifest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I also added in tools:replace in manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="c.x.y">

    <!--<compatible-screens>-->

        <!--&lt;!&ndash; all small size screens &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash; <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="mdpi"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="small" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="hdpi"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="small" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="xhdpi"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="small" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="480"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="small" /> &lt;!&ndash; xxhdpi &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="640"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="small" /> &lt;!&ndash; xxxhdpi &ndash;&gt;-->


        <!--&lt;!&ndash; all normal size screens &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--&lt;!&ndash; <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="mdpi"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="hdpi"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="xhdpi"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="420"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="480"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="560"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
        <!--<screen-->
            <!--android:screenDensity="640"-->
            <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash; all small size screens &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash; <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="mdpi"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="small" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="hdpi"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="small" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="xhdpi"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="small" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="480"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="small" /> &lt;!&ndash; xxhdpi &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="640"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="small" /> &lt;!&ndash; xxxhdpi &ndash;&gt;-->


    <!--&lt;!&ndash; all normal size screens &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--&lt;!&ndash; <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" /> &ndash;&gt;-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="mdpi"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="hdpi"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="xhdpi"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="420"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="480"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="560"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--<screen-->
    <!--android:screenDensity="640"-->
    <!--android:screenSize="normal" />-->
    <!--</compatible-screens>-->

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label, android:icon, android:allowBackup, android:smallScreens, android:xlargeScreens">
```

Thanks.

Comment: put your manifest here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

Instead of using the tools:replace in application tag, i moved in inside the < support-screen > and it worked.

```
 <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="false"
        tools:replace="android:smallScreens, android:xlargeScreens"
        />
```